# Function, that turns a word in a string to stars

Tags: python, function

Im doing an exercise, where im defining a function that takes two inputs - a sentence and a word, that will be replaced by stars in the sentence input.

Problem is, I cant get the final output to put spaces in between words, ie it prints all the words crammed together. Any help please ?

```
def censor(text, word):

  lis = text.split()

  output =""

  p = []

  for w in lis:
    if w != word:
      p.append(w)

    else:
      l = len(w)
      y = "*" * l
      p.append(y)

  output = output.join(p)

  print output

  censor("Hello world televison", "world")
```

Comment: Which class are you taking?

Comment: codeacademy.com

Comment: You just need to change `output = output.join(p)` to `output = ' '.join(p)`.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm -- pythons join is the opposite way round from what is normally found in other languages (and intuition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to initialize `output` to an empty string first. You can just do

```
 output = " ".join(p)
```

Notice the `" ".join()`, that is what determines how you are joining your strings. In this case, it's a single space. Also, you need to return something from your function, so instead of using `print` you should do

```
return output
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution, even though it's a little tricky, it should handle all the different cases that can occur:

```
def censor(text, word):
    text = '.' + text + '.'
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if text[i].lower() == word[0].lower():
            toCensor = True
            for j in range(len(word)):
                if text[i + j].lower() != word[j].lower():
                    toCensor = False
                    break
            if toCensor:
                if (ord(text[i - 1]) < ord('A') or ord(text[i - 1]) > ord('z'))\
                and (ord(text[i + len(word)]) < ord('A') or ord(text[i + len(word)]) > ord('z')):
                    lst = list(text)
                    for j in range(len(word)):
                        lst[i + j] = '*'
                    text = "".join(lst)
    lst = list(text)
    lst = lst[1 : -1]
    return "".join(lst)

censor("World worlds world television", "world")

>>> ***** worlds ***** television
```

It handles capital letters and all the punctuation.